# Add drawings to pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to add some draw objects to pgfplot (gnuplot), MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% define lengths and coordinates
\def\xinit{0}
\def\yinit{-2.5}
\def\hgt{0.5}
\def\wa{1.}
\def\wb{0.5}
\def\wc{1}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={x},
ylabel={y},
restrict x to domain=0:2*pi,
no markers,
clip = false,
]

\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, very thick] {set xrange [0:2*pi];
    set samples 1000;
plot sin(x^2) w l};
\draw (\xinit,\yinit) rectangle ++(\wa, \hgt) coordinate (a1);
\fill[red] (\xinit,\yinit) rectangle (\xinit +\wa,\yinit +\hgt);
\draw (a1) -- +(2,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I don't understand why the first rectangle is drawn wrong, it should be the same as the second one (red). Next, I want to sequentially draw several objects with known length. The last command shows my attempt to firstly define coordinate `(a1)`, then use this coordinate as initial for the next object: that should be a horizontal line from `(a1)` of length 2 (actually from `(a1) + (0,-\hgt /2)` -- the middle of the right side of red rectangle). So, if I explicitly set coordinates this works, but `+` or `++` method doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `axis direction cs` (in addition to `+` or `++`) to make it work. The PGFPlots manual states in [section 4.17.1 on page 355 (v1.17) - Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=355):

> While `axis cs` allows to supply *absolute positions*, `axis direction cs`
> supplies *directions*. It allows to express *relative* positions, including
> lengths and dimensions, by means of axis coordinates.
>
> As noted in the documentation for `axis cs`, adding two coordinates by means
> of the TikZ `++` operator may have unexpected effects. The correct way for
> `++` operations is `axis direction cs`: [...]

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % define lengths and coordinates
        \def\xinit{0}
        \def\yinit{-2.5}
        \def\hgt{0.5}
        \def\wa{1.}
        \def\wb{0.5}
        \def\wc{1}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        restrict x to domain=0:2*pi,
        no markers,
        clip = false,
    ]
        \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, very thick] {
            set xrange [0:2*pi];
            set samples 1000;
            plot sin(x^2) w l;
        };
        % this doesn't work (as expected), ...
        \draw (\xinit,\yinit) rectangle ++(\wa, \hgt) coordinate (a1);
        % ... because you have to use `axis direction cs:', too.
        \draw [ultra thick,thick,blue]
            (\xinit,\yinit) rectangle ++(axis direction cs:\wa, \hgt)
                coordinate (a1);

        \fill [red] (\xinit,\yinit) rectangle (\xinit +\wa,\yinit +\hgt);

        \draw (a1) -- +(2,0);
        % the same here
        \draw [very thick,green] (a1) -- +(axis direction cs:2,0);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the zoomed result of above code]