# How can I accive incremental positioning of an \draw within a pgfplot (groupplot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I've been working with Tikz for 2 days now and stumbled across the following problem while creating a graphic and can't quite explain what I'm doing wrong.

I want to add an arrow or path to the graphic, if I use absolute coordinates they seem to be processed correctly. When adding incremental coordinates, the location/base vector seems to be interpreted correctly, but the direction vector seems to be processed completely wrong.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or if this is a feature/bug?

Attached is a MWE and the result I get and the result I expect (hardcoded).

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom= 25mm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset
{
    width = 12cm, 
    height = 43mm,
    compat=newest,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[step=1, color=gray!50, thin] (0,-5) grid (15,5);
        
        \begin{groupplot}
        [
        group style={group size=1 by 2, vertical sep = 1cm,},
        axis x line = center, 
        axis y line = left, 
        xmax = 10,
        domain = 0:10,
        samples = 100,
        ]
            \nextgroupplot[title = What I get]
                \addplot[color = red] {2*cos(180*x/pi)};
                \draw[blue,dashed] (0,1.5) rectangle ++(8,-3);
                % Base seems correct but target point currupt 
                \draw[->,green,very thick] (3,0) -- ++(5,1.5); 
            \nextgroupplot[title = What I want]
                \addplot[color = red] {2*cos(180*x/pi)};
                \draw[blue,dashed] (0,1.5) rectangle (8,-1.5);
                \draw[->,green,very thick] (3,0) -- (8,1.5); 
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[Open in Overleaf](https://de.overleaf.com/read/pmcqyrwvmvyh)

[image: What I get vs. what I want]

Comment: Does [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358706/263192](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358706/263192) help?

Comment: Wonderful, that solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seams you found a *bug*: all relative positioning seams to get shifted the amount above the origin. You can see this shifting ++(0,0), like this line inside your code:

```
% showing buggy position ++(0,0),   
\draw[red,thick] (3,0) ++(0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
```

I get a (cliped half) circle on position (3,2). Plotted function ranges from -2 to 2. If I change the scaling of cosinus, this half circle shifts to above (3,0) on the top of visible plot window.

I can't tell if this bug is known or not.

To avoid repetitive point declarations in you code, you could use more `coordinate` to define key points of your plot, and (...|-...) style of point declaration if you need to filter horizontal position or vertical positions of defined points. I illustrate in the code below:

```
\nextgroupplot[title = What I get]
      \addplot[color = red] {2*cos(180*x/pi)};
      \draw (0,-1.5) coordinate (b1)
            (8,1.5) coordinate (b2)
            (3,0) coordinate (a1);
      \draw[blue,dashed] (b1) rectangle (b2);
      \draw[->,green,very thick] (a1) -- (b2);
      % making a new box from position (3,0) of same size of previous
      \draw (a1|-b1) rectangle (b2);
```

Result:

[image: result from code]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! As mentioned in the comment section of my post this "bug" seems to been known. `axis direction cs:` helped. 

I was searching for the `coordinate` command, but helped me out with empty `node`s :D Therefor as well thank you!